# Marginal likelihood derivation for normal likelihood and prior

Tags: probability, bayesian, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

For a normal likelihood
$$
P(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{b}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{Gb}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_y)
$$
and a normal prior
$$
P(\mathbf{b}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}_p, \mathbf{\Sigma}_p)
$$
I'm trying derive the evidence (or marginal likelihood) $P(\mathbf{y})$ where
$$
P(\mathbf{y}) = \int P(\mathbf{y, b}) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{b} = \int P(\mathbf{y|b}) P(\mathbf{b}) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{b} = \mathcal{N}(\mu_{\mathrm{ML}}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathrm{ML}})
$$
**Could anyone point me at a source for this derivation (or reproduce it)?**

I tried doing it in an indirect way by first finding the posterior $P(\mathbf{b|y})$ and then via Bayes' theorem writing
$$
\ln{P(\mathbf{y})} = \ln{P(\mathbf{y|b})} + \ln{P(\mathbf{b})} - \ln{P(\mathbf{b|y})},
$$
then by grouping terms quadratic in $\mathbf{y}$ and using the Woodbury identity I managed to show that the marginal likelihood covariance is $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathrm{ML}} = \mathbf{G} \mathbf{\Sigma}_p \mathbf{G}^{\top} + \mathbf{\Sigma}_y$, but I haven't been able to get the mean $\mu_{\mathrm{ML}}$.

I'm sure the integral can be evaluated directly to get the answer, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: We derive this marginal in our textbook [Bayesian Essentials with R](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO). With the same arguments as in [Jarad's answer.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/308911/7224)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is to rewrite $y$ as
$$y = Gb + e$$
where $G$ is known, $b\sim N(\mu_p,\Sigma_p)$ and, independently, $e\sim N(0,\Sigma_y)$.
Now $y$ is just the sum of two independent normals which is fully determined by its mean and covariance matrix.
The mean is
$$E[Y] = E[Gb] + E[e] = GE[b] + 0 = G\mu_p$$
and the variance is
$$Var[y] = Var[Gb] + Var[e] = GVar[b]G^\top + Var[e] = G\Sigma_pG^\top +\Sigma_y$$.
Since $b$ and $e$ are independent, the covariance is zero.
Thus the marginal likelihood is
$$y\sim N(G\mu_p,G\Sigma_pG^\top + \Sigma_y).$$