# How to derive marginal likelihood equation for linear regression as product of two Gaussians?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, linear-model, likelihood, marginal-distribution

I understand that marginal-likelihood can be derived as answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/308911/305392). Quoting the same proof from [MATHEMATICS FOR
MACHINE LEARNING](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf) book (9.3.5) Page 312,
[image]

The same book mentions that we can derive this using multiplication of two Gaussians (which is not used in the above derivation) (6.5.2)(Page 201)
[image]

But, as you can see we need to have same random variable $x$ to apply the above rule, MML book mentioned in Chapter 9 that we can change $y$ in form of $\theta$ and then use above rule. (Page 312 again)
[image]

I am not able to convert $y$ in form of $\theta$ as suggested here and derive the marginal likelihood. Can someone help on this?